# CICD Authentication using SPN

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, spn

I am creating a CI CD pipeline to move code between dev and test instances of databricks. I am able to achieve this using my personal token. Now, I am trying to do the same thing using a SPN and when I do the same, i get the following error.

**HTTP ERROR 403
Problem accessing /api/2.0/workspace/mkdirs. Reason:
    User not authorized.**

Can any of you help me resolve this error or provide any links which talks about how to use SPN to authenticate from devops to databricks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your SPN have Contributor Role on either the Databricks resources or Azure Resource Groups ? It could be throwing a very similar error if not.

Comment: Thanks Axel. That was the problem. After giving the right permissions, it worked. Thanks much for your reply